# What's wrong with my Java code?? (beginner)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Library {

    Library() {
    }

    public void getFinishedBooks(HashMap<String, Boolean> library) {
        if(library.size() < 1)
            System.out.println("Error! Library is empty.");
        else {
            for(String book : library.keySet()); {
                if((library.get(book)) == true)
                    System.out.println(library.get(book));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, Boolean> myBooks = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        myBooks.put("Road Down the Funnel", true);
        myBooks.put("Rat: A Biology", false);
        myBooks.put("TimeIn", true);
        myBooks.put("3D Food Printing", false);

        Library myLibrary = new Library();
        myLibrary.getFinishedBooks(myBooks);
    }
}
```

It's a basic library program. I can't seem to find what's causing the error...

Error message: "Error! Cannot find symbol if((library.get(book)) == true)

symbol: variable book

location: class Library

Comment: 1) Start with the proper formatting. 2) Remove `;` at line ` for(String book : library.keySet());`.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the `;` in the line

```
 for(String book : library.keySet())
```

Its always better to use IDE when you start learning the language. Warnings in the IDE will help you solve the issue quickly.

Comment: OMG thank you so much... I was going mad....